# Configure multiple instances of app wirelessly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth, push-notification

I have an app being used in schools, and one of the features is that they can create classes online and enter class codes on each iPad to access a list of students that they can select. What I would like to do is let the teacher configure multiple instances of these apps (i.e. for a "class set" of iPads) from one parent device, or even via the web. It would involve sending a small amount of data, most likely just a class code, to each iPad.

I know what to do once it is sent to the app, the question is how to get it there without making the teacher open the app on every device and manually add the class code. Could this be done via Bluetooth or even Push Notifications? Which option would be better?

EDIT: A bit more information - The class code corresponds to an actual class on the server, so a group of students. The students simply type in a class code and select their name from a list.

Comment: Could you clarify how the student list is involved? You say you enter a class code on each ipad to access the students? Is a class a lesson or is it a group of students? Do students log in on their iPads?

Comment: The class code corresponds to an actual class on the server, so a group of students. The students simply type in a class code and select their name from a list.

Comment: Right. So the teacher creates a class code and assigns all the students. Then somewhere physically are the 30 or so iPads that need to enter the class code? Do the students own/carry the devices, or are they in the ownership of the teacher? Does the code need to be re-applied (reliably) before every class begins? Is the current process of student typing the code not working well?

Comment: Schools usually have iPad carts or similar with multiple iPads, usually 20 or more, so they'd be in possession of the teacher/school. The code only needs to be entered once, ever, and then it gets added to a list of classes to choose from. The current method works ok, but its younger kids (kindergarten - 2nd) so its just a value-add feature I'm thinking would make teacher's lives easier for initial configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Apple's guidelines for deploying devices in a school via MDM:

[iOS Education Deployment Guide](http://images.apple.com/education/docs/ios_6_education_deployment_guide.pdf)

That covers a lot that might give you ideas about how to deploy.